# How to Implement Biological Neuron Activations in Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: python, neural-network, activation-function, implementation, bioinformatics

In artificial neural networks, activation functions are used for neurons, i.e. the **sigmoid** activation:

[image: Sigmoid function]

Which can be implemented in code as (in Python):

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

How can we implement a biological activation function, such as the **[Hodgkin-Huxley model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model)**, whose mathematical form is:

[image]

Where:

- Cm: Capacitance
- Vm: Membrane potential

As mentioned on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model) page,

> The typical Hodgkin–Huxley model treats each component of an excitable
>   cell as an electrical element (as shown in the figure). The lipid
>   bilayer is represented as a capacitance (Cm). Voltage-gated ion
>   channels are represented by electrical conductances (gn, where n is
>   the specific ion channel) that depend on both voltage and time. Leak
>   channels are represented by linear conductances (gL). The
>   electrochemical gradients driving the flow of ions are represented by
>   voltage sources (En) whose voltages are determined by the ratio of the
>   intra- and extracellular concentrations of the ionic species of
>   interest. Finally, ion pumps are represented by current sources
>   (Ip).[clarification needed] The membrane potential is denoted by Vm.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiking_neural_network